# Converting KML to CSV or SHP using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, csv, kml

I'm using ArcMap 10. Is there a way to convert a .kml file into a .csv to check the attributes or a .shp to import it straight into ArcMap?

I've tried downloading various programmes to convert it but they either don't work properly or my university won't let me download them.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgc4p4z8dzamhqj/UK%20postcode%20districts.kml) is the .kml file in question.

Comment: csv available here http://www.doogal.co.uk/PostcodeDistricts.php

Answer (score 6):

Use the **[KML To Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004w000000)** tool which you can find and open via the **Search** window or in [ArcToolbox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003q0000001m000000.htm) under the **Conversion Tools**.

> Converts a KML or KMZ file into feature classes and a layer file. The
>   layer file maintains the symbology found within the original KML or
>   KMZ file.

You can go from the feature class or layer (created by that tool) to a shapefile using **[Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000035000000)** (or Export Data in the Table of Contents).

[image: fromkml]

Answer (score 5):

You can do that easily in QGIS.

- change your KMZ to KML (open in google earth and save as KML)
- open as a vector layer in QGIS
- right click the layer -> save as -> choose ESRI shapefile from the dropdown
- do the same with CSV from the dropdown

I have just done this with your data and it seems to provide all the necessary data you require - takes 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using FWTools.  Its an open source commandline tool.  The command you would want to use to convert the KML to a SHP would be the following:

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" c:\temp\outshapefile.shp C:\temp\inkml.kml